# Texttospeech list of supported languages

Tags: android

I can't find list of supported languages for TextToSpeech. What languages ​​are supported ?

Comment: Look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) it is from 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Introduction to Text-to-speech Android developer blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html).

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

> The TTS engine that ships with the Android platform supports a number
>   of languages: English, French, German, Italian and Spanish. Also,
>   depending on which side of the Atlantic you are on, American and
>   British accents for English are both supported.

You can also query the Android system to find out if a language is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Languages available may vary across many devices, so you should check the availability during runtime. You can check if language is supported using [`isLanguageAvailable(Locale loc)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable%28java.util.Locale%29).

You will get one of the [following](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#LANG_AVAILABLE) responses:
`LANG_AVAILABLE`, `LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE`, `LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE`, `LANG_MISSING_DATA` or `LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED`.